# Make row names of one table columns of the other MySQL

Tags: mysql, row

I don't know if this is possible or not.
I have `Table1` with the following fields.

```
No

A
B
C
D
```

I want `table2's` column names to be table1's row names (varchar(20) each, all null's)

```
A B C D
```

If I add a row in table1, table2 column should get appended too.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to make the table have the column names?  Or select the data with those values as the column names?

Comment: I want to make the table2 have the column names of table1 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some info on a few pseudo solutions in T-SQL (SQL Server) here, some of which may be transferable to MySQL: http://sqlserveradvisor.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/sql-server-convert-rows-to-columns.html
However there's no simple method.

The best I could come up with (again in T-SQL) is this dynamic SQL solution:

```
    declare @tempTable table (ColumnName nvarchar(10))
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
    insert @tempTable
    select 'Col1'
    union select 'Col2'
    union select 'Col3'
    select @sql = isnull(@sql+ ',','') + '1 ' + quotename(ColumnName)
    from @tempTable
    set @sql = 'select ' + @sql
    exec(@sql)
```

--EDIT--

I've managed to try out a script on MySQL (via the online host here: http://headfirstlabs.com/sql_hands_on/hf01.htm).  The below code works with the demo database there, so should work on your table.  I made it slightly overcomplicated by having the columns contain data with the column number because I got a bit confused, but hopefully it's all helpful so I've left it in for now.

```
set @test:='select';
set @i:=1;
select @test:=concat(@test, ' ',case when @i>1 then ',' else '' end, ' ''Col', @i, ''' as ', last_name) , @i:=@i+1 from my_contacts;
select @test;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @test;
execute stmt1;
```

(simplified MySQL Version)

```
set @sql:='select';
select @sql:=concat(@sql, case when @sql>'select' then ', ' else ' ' end, '0 as ', last_name) from my_contacts;
select @sql;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
execute stmt1;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No worries - I've added an edit to include a version which I got working on MySQL - hope that does the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. But if you only want the data from those rows to become rows in a `SELECT`, then you can do something like this:

```
select 
  max(case when no = 'A' then col end) as A,
  max(case when no = 'B' then col end) as B,
  max(case when no = 'C' then col end) as C,
  max(case when no = 'D' then col end) as D
from table1
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfd45/1)

If you want to go the opposite way and turn columns into rows then you use a `UNION ALL`:

```
select col1 No
from table1
union all
select col2 No
from table1
union all
select col3 No
from table1
union all
select col4 No
from table1
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c927/3)

Comment: Oh no! Sorry If I wasn't clear. I want the column names of tableB to be row names of tableA.

Comment: What happens when I add a row to table1 in future

Comment: You will have to do it dynamically. I am working on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by using only query, you need to work in server side language to achieve this.

Comment: ya.. true.. I was wondering if a query could do that.. would save me some time.. :)